# How to make Class.forName return array type?

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible that `Class.forName` can return an array type? Now when I use `Class.forName("byte[]")` it throws `NoClassFound` exception.

Or generally, how to get `Type[].class` from `Type.class`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(byte[].class.getName());
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("[B");
        System.out.println(byte[].class==clazz);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

byte[].class's name is "[B";

byte[].class==clazz is true

[Ljava.lang.String; for String[]

[Lpacket.to.YourClass;  for YourClass[]

Comment: Is there a way to get the primitive type's short name like "B", "I", etc.

Comment: There are only a few primitive types in Java,you can check it one by one.

Comment: ok, that seems is the only way

Comment: You missed the trailing semicolon, they should be `[Ljava.lang.String;` , `Lpath.to.YourClass;`, etc.